# datalist custom paging in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am doing custom paging for a datalist.Below method gets the required page numbers.
My problem is the click event is not being fired during debug.
Can anyone tel where the problem is.

```
 private void BindPageNumbers(int TotalRecords)
            {

                int counter = 0;
                for(int i=0;i<TotalRecords;i=i+5)
                {
                    counter=counter+1;
                    LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
                    lnk.Click += new EventHandler(lbl_click);
                    lnk.ID = "lnkPage" + (counter).ToString();
                    lnk.Text = (counter).ToString();
                    pages.Controls.Add(lnk);
                    Label spacer = new Label();
                    spacer.Text = "&nbsp;";
                    pages.Controls.Add(spacer);
                }                
            }
void lbl_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LinkButton lnk = sender as LinkButton;
            int Currentpage = int.Parse(lnk.Text);
            ListDataBinding_paging(2, this.Days, (Currentpage-1)*5, 5);
        }
```

Here "ListDataBinding_paging" is the method from where the datalist is being filled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating your page link buttons dynamically. So they need to be re-created in every post-back early in the life-cycle. I suspect that `BindPageNumbers` is getting called after the post event data is processed and hence the click event does not get generated.

I suggest you to invoke `BindPageNumbers` in `page_load` for creating your buttons early in the life cycle. You can store the total records count in the view-state. If `page_load` doesn't help then try `LoadViewState` override - put the code after call to base implementation - something like

protected override void LoadViewState(Object savedState)
{
   base.LoadViewState(savedState);
   BindPageNumbers((int)ViewState["TotalRecords"]);
}